# x86 16Bit - Changing text background & color after changing palette

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

I've been working with bmps, therefore changed the color palette of the program

Now text is printed dark blue with black background..

Is it prossible to change the color to a specific color from the palette?

I'm using `int 21h` / `ah=09h` to print "score: " and `int 21h` / `ah=02h` to print numbers (chars), video mode 13h

Comment: Try BIOS `int 10`, services 09 and 0E looks promising: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-e.html  ... or just create your own font + sprite routine, at least it will be probably much faster than BIOS, unless you implement it in extra inefficient way.

Comment: @Ped7g thank you! it helped.
Can you please submit it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: too lazy to do that, feel free to post your own answer (but make it a proper one, imagine you don't know the solution yet, and the answer should help you). Actually formulating your new knowledge in a way to make it helpful for others will very likely give you new insight into the knowledge itself, or at least it will be a practice of SO formatting skills. ... also it's quite likely this is duplicate already, but I didn't search for one, you may try that first and marking your Q as duplicate if you find sufficient answer (you may also find out additional info from other questions). :) GL.